# Changing width and height in html

Tags: html, css

The width and hight of following code change, on the change of resolution of different devices.

```
<div style="background-color:orange;height:125px;width:75px;">
This div has height and width applied.
</div>
```

Is there any way to prevent change of width and height and make it retain same width and height for all resolution.

Note: For this I have also tried with zooming ( in and out ) the html page which changes the width and height of the div.

Comment: By resolution do you mean pixel density, or screen/viewport size? Technically speaking with height and width explicitly declared, the element should stay the same size.

Comment: @Terry I mean both, pixel as well as screen/viewport size

Comment: You could use 'cm' for example or 'dppx'

Comment: You are defining the height and width in px. It should stay same

Comment: If you mean you want to maintain scale, you should look at using `<meta>` tags: `<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width; initial-scale=1.0; maximum-scale=1.0;">`

Comment: @Terry I agree with you, but when I check my web-app on different devices of higher pixel density and viewport I got fixed width but changed height.

Comment: That's not really possible, unless you have overriding styles. Can you demonstrate your problem in a fiddle, or in a screenshot?

Comment: @Terry please check this page http://www.quackit.com/css/tutorial/css_height_width.cfm

try changing resolution by zooming in and out to as high level as possible

Comment: When you zoom, the elements will of course change size as the resolution (dpi) will change. Why would you want to prevent that at the first place?

Comment: @Terry actually I built a webpage and entire page looks ugly on other devices because of this prob, is their any way I can prevent it

Comment: Then you should consider using responsive layours, not pixel-precise ones. **The problem does not lie with zoom**, it lies with the viewport size (calling it 'screen resolution' is actually a misnomer).

Comment: @Terry I surprise, I am using media query and the page still does not show expected view. Would you mind writing answer

Answer (score 1):

you need to probably add a viewport meta between your head tags:

`<meta name="viewport" content="initial-scale=1">`

http://webdesign.tutsplus.com/articles/quick-tip-dont-forget-the-viewport-meta-tag--webdesign-5972

Answer (score 0):

Use percentage instead of fixed pixels like :

```
<div style="background-color:orange;height:20%;width:20%;">
```

this will retain height and width on page resizing

Comment: I want to specify only in pixel

Answer (score 0):

U can resize with the @-viewport CSS Declaration! This is best practice

Comment: could you describe a little.